# casting a List<object> into NancyFx response

Tags: odata, nancy

I am trying to build an Nancy OData support app using LinqToQuerystring. I got below sample code. it is working for any query url like:

### http:/test/?$filter=Recommended eq true

Get["/test"] = _ =>

{ 
                    var dict = (IDictionary)Request.Query.ToDictionary();

```
                new List<Movie>
                 {
                     new Movie
                  {
                  Title = "Matrix (The)",
                  ReleaseDate = new DateTime(1999, 3, 31),
                  DurationInMinutes = 136,                    
                  MetaScore = 73,
                  Director = "Wachowski Brothers",
                  Recommended = true
                  },
                 new Movie
               {
               Title = "There and Back Again, An Unexpected Journey",
               ReleaseDate = new DateTime(2012, 12, 14),
               DurationInMinutes = 169,
               MetaScore = 58,
               Director = "Peter Jackson",
               Recommended = false
               }
              }.AsQueryable() 
                 .LinqToQuerystring(dict);
               return dict;
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by calling ToDictionary first.

i.e

```
var dict = (IDictionary<string, object>) Request.Query.ToDictionary();
...
.LinqToQuerystring(dict);
```

[image]

This is probably because of the way LinqToQuerystring handles Dictionary under the hood, outputting them in an intermediate window causes:

```
(IDictionary<string, object>) Request.Query
{Nancy.DynamicDictionary}
    [Nancy.DynamicDictionary]: {Nancy.DynamicDictionary}
    Keys: Count = 2
    Values: Count = 2

(IDictionary<string, object>) Request.Query.ToDictionary()
Count = 2
    [0]: {[one, one]}
    [1]: {[two, 2]}
```

**Edit:**

Based on your comment I assume you want to ALWAYS return JSON.

If that's the case the way you would do that is to return:

```
return Response.AsJson(dict);
```

This will serialize the dictionary as JSON for you.

Comment: still I couldn't return results with (return dict;)using above help.
Also i tried to typecast to Response.:
var resp = (Response)dict;

 still no luck!

Comment: How are you trying to return it? Your sample emits the return statement and you're note telling how you're accessing it.

Comment: here is my code:
Get["/test"] = _ =>
                    { var dict = (IDictionary<string, object>)Request.Query.ToDictionary();
                      
                        new List<Movie>
                         {
                             new Movie
                                 {...},
                                                                              
                             new Movie
                                 {...}
                         }.AsQueryable() 
                         .LinqToQuerystring(dict);
                       return dict;
       }

Comment: @user998677 can you please update your original question. It's hard to read unformatted code...

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for your kind help. I got one resolution for this:

var javaScriptSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

string jsonString = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(dict);

Comment: @Raj I've updated my answer to do what you want to do.

Comment: thanks phil, yes i always want to return Json.
the " Response.AsJson(dict)"  didn't work for me. so i used javaScriptSerializer. (you can try & test once with original code)